# Using pd.DataFrame.sample on dask dataframe with groupby

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby, dask

I have a very large dataframe that I am resampling a large number of times, so I'd like to use dask to speed up the process. However, I'm running into challenges with the groupby apply. An example data frame would be

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'sample_id':np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).repeat(100),
                       'param1':random.sample(range(1, 1000), 400)})
test_df.set_index('sample_id', inplace=True)
```

which I can normally groupby and resample using

```py
N = 5;i=1

test = test_df\
    .groupby(['sample_id'])\
    .apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, n=N, replace=False)\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
test['bootstrap'] = i
test['resample'] = N
```

Which I wrap into a method that iterates over an N gradient i times. The actual dataframe is very large with a number of columns, and before anyone suggests, this method is a little bit faster than an np.random.choice approach on the index-- it's all in the groupby. I've run the overall procedure through a multiprocessing method, but I wanted to see if I could get a bit more speed out of a dask version of the same. The problem is the documentation suggests that if you index and partition then you get complete groups per partition-- which is not proving true.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

df1 = dd.from_pandas(test_df, npartitions=8)
df1=df1.persist()
df1.divisions
```

creates

> ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd')

which unsurprisingly results in a failure

```py
N = 5;i=1

test = df1\
    .groupby(['sample_id'])\
    .apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, n=N, replace=False)\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
test['bootstrap'] = i
test['resample'] = N
```

> ValueError: Metadata inference failed in `groupby.apply(sample)`.
> You have supplied a custom function and Dask is unable to
> determine the type of output that that function returns.
> To resolve this please provide a meta= keyword.
> The docstring of the Dask function you ran should have more information.
> Original error is below:
> ValueError("Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'")

I have dug all around the documentation on keywords, dask dataframes & partitions, and groupby aggregations and simply am simply missing the solution if it's there in the documents. Any advice on how to create a smarter set of partitions and/or get the groupby with sample playing nice with dask would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: HI Danielle, does my answer help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what you are trying to achieve and why you need to add `replace=False` (which is default) but the following code work for me. I just need to add `meta`.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

df1 = dd.from_pandas(test_df.reset_index(), npartitions=8)

N = 5
i = 1

test = df1\
    .groupby(['sample_id'])\
    .apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=N),
           meta={"sample_id": "object",
                 "param1": "f8"})\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
test['bootstrap'] = i
test['resample'] = N
```

If you then want to drop `sample_id` you just need to add

```py
df = df.drop("sample_id", axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! If you know, could you point me to where in the docs it describes this? I swear I spent a day in the documentation and did not understand this. For what I'm achieving-- I'm iteratively downsampling a high-dimensional dataframe by group and testing for the N when internal characteristics stop being true. The replace=False was a relic from the complexity of the downsampling options, with apologies for not pulling that out before posting the example.

Comment: HI Danielle, for which part do you need links to docs? What is happening within the apply is pure `pandas` (I mean `x.sample()`), while for the meta is a typical `dask` thing. You need to know in advance what's the output for the given computation and state the `dtypes`.